# How can I let ES support mixed type of a field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am saving logs to Elasticsearch for analysis but I found there are mixed types of a particular field which causing error when indexing the document.

For example, I may save below log to the index where `uuid` is an object.

```
POST /index-000001/_doc
{
  "uuid": {"S": "001"}
}
```

but from another event, the log would be:

```
POST /index-000001/_doc
{
  "uuid": "001"
}
```

the second POST will fail because the type of `uuid` is not an object. so I get this error: `object mapping for [uuid] tried to parse field [uuid] as object, but found a concrete value`

I wonder what the best solution for that? I can't change the log because they are from different application. The first log is from the data of dynamodb while the second one is the data from application. How can I save both types of logs into ES?

If I disable dynamic mapping, I will have to specify all fields in the index mapping. For any new fields, I am not able to search them. so I do need dynamic mapping.

There will be many cases like that. so I am looking for a solution which can cover all conflict fields.

Comment: This is where a [default ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) would shine and make sure everything has the same format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly possible using [ingest pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-processors.html) which are run *before* the indexing process.

The following would be a solution for your particular use case, albeit somewhat onerous:

1. create a pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/uuid_normalize
{
  "description" : "Makes sure uuid is a hash map",
  "processors" : [
    {
       "script": {
        "source": """
          if (ctx.uuid != null && !(ctx.uuid instanceof java.util.HashMap)) {
            ctx.uuid = ['S': ctx.uuid]; // hash map init
          }
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2. run the pipeline when ingesting a new doc

```
POST /index-000001/_doc
{
  "uuid": {"S": "001"}
}

POST /index-000001/_doc?pipeline=uuid_normalize     <------
{
  "uuid": "001"
}
```

You could now extend this to be as generic as you like but it is assumed that you know what you expect as input in each and every doc. In other words, unlike dynamic templates, you need to know what you want to safeguard against.

You can read more about painless script operators [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-operators-reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot.
You should either normalize all your field in a way or another.
Or use 2 separate field.

I can suggest to use a field like this :

```
"uuid": {"key": "S", "value": "001"}
```

and skip the key when not necessary.
But you will have to preprocess your value before ingestion.